# Boost.Lambda and Boost.Function don't play nicely with Boost.Array, why?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function, boost-lambda

I'm running into extremely frustrating problems with Boost.

When I try running something as simple as

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/core.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::function<size_t(boost::array<size_t, 1>, size_t)> f =
        boost::lambda::_1[boost::lambda::_2];
    return 0;
}
```

I get back:

```
error C2440: 'return' :
    cannot convert from 'boost::lambda::detail::unspecified' to 'size_t'
```

#### Why is this error occurring, and how do I make Boost.Lambda do what I need?

*(Yes, I'm aware I can use Boost.Phoenix et al. too, but that's not the point of the question.)*

Comment: @user1095108: To make a lambda using boost.lambda that has the effect of `boost::lambda::_1[boost::lambda::_2]` obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subscript operator in boost::lambda supports only the following types (from `lambda/detail/operator_return_type_traits.hpp` of my install of boost 1.53):

`A*`, `A[N]`, `std::map`, `std::multimap`, `std::deque`, `std::vector`, `std::basic_string`. Everything else becomes `detail::unspecified`, which you see in your compiler diagnostic.

To make boost.lambda do what you need, you can submit a patch to `operator_return_type_traits.hpp` adding support for `boost::array`

Comment: Oooooh wow, I would never have guessed they'd special-cased it. +1 thanks a bunch for the pointer.